# How to get All apenders form log4j2 root logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j, append, log4j2

In log4j 1.2 we can get all the appenders of root logger in the following way.

```
Enumeration<Appender> it = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
```

In log4j2 is there something similar to get the root logger and its appenders ?

Answer (score 3):

you can get all appenders from LoggerConfig

```
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext logContext = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager
            .getContext(false);

    Map<String, LoggerConfig> map = logContext.getConfiguration().getLoggers();

    for(LoggerConfig c:map.values()){
        System.out.println(c.getAppenders());
    }
```

Comment: This reruns the creation of the appenders

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you need something like this (maybe there is something less complicated...):
Taken from

> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server:

```
LoggerContextFactory factory = LogManager.getFactory();
ContextSelector selector = ((Log4jContextFactory) factory).getSelector();
for (LoggerContext ctx : selector.getLoggerContexts()) {
    ...
    Map<String, Appender> m = ctx.getConfiguration().getAppenders();
    ...
}
```